# What is the difference between using helper_method in a controller or placing the method in application_helper.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been learning RoR and have some problem understanding the difference between these two files.

module ApplicationHelper

```
    def gravatar_for(chef, options = { size: 80 })
        gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(chef.email.downcase)
        size = options[:size]
        gravatar_url = "http://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
        image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: chef.chefname, class: "gravatar")
    end
end
```

and

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base  
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?, :require_user  

        def current_user
            @current_user ||= Chef.find(session[:chef_id]) if session[:chef_id]
        end

        def logged_in?
            !!current_user
        end

        def require_user
            if !logged_in?
            flash[:danger] = "You must be logged in to perform this action"
            redirect_to recipes_path
        end
    end
end
```

Are these interchangeable?  Could I put everything in applicationhelper.rb or use helper_method for all?  Everything works great, just looking for some clarity.

Comment: If you put method in a helper, you can't use it in a controller directly (and vice versa, hence the `helper_method` thing)

Comment: The method in ApplicationController has access to class and instance variables, the method in ApplicationHelper not. (e.g. it would not be possible to write the `current_user` and `logged_in?` methods in ApplicationHelper)

Comment: @Kris: helper methods are usually executed in the context of a view, where there are methods like `current_user` and `signed_in?`